# I want to change my app name to S&S in flutter ios in info.plist but i am getting error

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use "&" in app name for ios. what's method . i want to change name in CFBundleName tag in info.plist file of flutter. i am getting error while compiling for ios app.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: error is "unknown ampersand-escape sequence at  line 14"   . i m using this code <key>CFBundleName</key>
  <string>S&S</string>

Comment: Have you tried to double the "&" in the value? This symbol name is ampersand and it must be used in the info.plist as an escape character like the backslash "\" in other languages/format. So simply try changing "S&S" to "S&&S"

Answer (score 1):

have to escape certain characters - & should be escaped using the XML entity `&amp;`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Escaping

Answer (score 1):

Can you try replacing `&` with `&amp;`?